# Electromagnet circut with backup capacitor to keep metal object on roof of car whilst driving

Tags: capacitor

I need a little help with an experiment. I am trying to attach a metal sign to the top of a vehicle using electromagnets. The idea is that we will place two electromagnets one at either end of the metal object and plug it into the cars 12VDC power supply. I would like the electro magnets to hold the 8kg container to the roof of the car whilst the vehicle is moving. We would also like to introduce a capacitor into the equation so that if the power is disconnected whilst driving the metal obect doesnt fall off. What size capacitor would i need if the electro magnets are 12w in total and i would like the backup or emergency supply to last for 1 hour. I would also like to introduce a kill switch or cut switch that when pushed will deactivate the cap and allow the object to be removed.

Comment: How long do you think the charge from a capacitor (even a very large one) would hold the electromagnet? A few microseconds? A few milliseconds?  Really not a good idea.

Comment: I'd use a roof rack.

Comment: A better idea may be to use permanent magnets e.g. https://www.topnotchsigns.co.uk/?page=School%20of%20Motoring

Comment: Assuming unit efficiency you would need 600F. Assuming that 6V is the last voltage your EM can run from you get a max cap value of 2.4kF. Let's say you can get away w/ 1kF. Such caps sorta exist, it's about 10$/F and about 1l/F. So you need 10k$ and 1 cubic metre. Maybe permanent magnets is a better choice.

Comment: I will not contribute to a topic where 8kg's of metal may come loose at highway speeds - any failure could kill someone.

Comment: What if we replaced the capacitor with a battery?

Comment: Bruce, the real issue is one of safety. A momentary failure of the electromagnet (poor joint/bump in the road) could cause an  8kg solid lump to depart at speed from the roof of your car potentially causing a fatal accident. A 'home brew' solution would not be covered by any insurance.

Comment: If the idea is just to make it easier to remove a magnetically mounted sign, then I'd look into how [these things operate](http://www.eclipsemagnetics.com/row/product-range/workholding/ax47-p-rectangular-premier-chuck.html)  That's a magnetic hold down used to hold steel objects for milling.  I'm pretty sure that somebody, somewhere has built a magnetic sign mount  with the same type of mechanism.  I just don't know what to call it.

Comment: is this one of those self-driving cars?

Comment: Thanks for the info Jlm, whilst i understand your concerns we are testing this and looking to come up with a solution. Whatever the final product will need to go through extensive testing in wind tunnels and meet certain criteria before it is allowed to be used in a public environment. The solution needs to have a theft proof element to it and that is why we are looking at options like this. A remote to deactivate the backup when the vehicle is switched off etc.

Comment: if you'd replace the capacitor with a battery, why not use the 12VDC plug as you already do? It's already backed by a battery

Comment: Neodymium magnets seem like a much safer solution ...

Answer (score 1):

> What size capacitor would i need if the electro magnets are 12w in total and I would like the backup or emergency supply to last for 1 hour.

The minimum capacitor size can be calculated by the law of conservation of energy. To run the electromagnets you need 12 watts for 1 hour. That means you need a total energy of:

$$ 12\:\mathrm W \cdot 1\:\text{hour}
= 12\:\mathrm W \cdot 3600\:\mathrm s
= 43200\:\mathrm{J} $$

That is, you need to store, at a minimum, 43200 [joules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule) of energy somewhere.

The energy \$E\$ stored in a capacitor with capacitance \$C\$ charged to voltage \$V\$ is:

$$ E = {1 \over 2} C V^2 $$

A key thing to realize here is that "capacitance" is not "capacity to store energy". The energy stored in a capacitor is a function of both voltage and capacitance, so a small capacitor charged to a high voltage, and a large capacitor charged to a low voltage could have the same stored energy.

But let's just assume that since you have a 12V power supply, you will be charging the capacitor to that voltage. In that case, to meet the minimum energy storage requirements, you will require a capacitance of:

$$ \begin{align}
43200\:\mathrm{J} &= 1/2 \cdot C \cdot (12\:\mathrm{V})^2 \\
43200\:\mathrm{J} &= C \cdot 72\:\mathrm{V}^2 \\
600\:\mathrm J / \mathrm V^2 &= C
\end{align} $$

A joule per volt squared is also known as a [farad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad). So you need a 600 farad capacitor charged to 12 volts to have enough stored energy to power your electromagnet. That's a pretty huge capacitor.

You could also use a smaller capacitor charged to a higher voltage. Each doubling of the voltage cuts the necessary capacitance to store the same energy by a factor of 4. So if you can charge it to 24V, then you need 150F. At 48V, 37.5F. These are still huge capacitors. If you get the voltage high enough, the capacitance required could be small, but a capacitor able to withstand such high voltages would still be physically large and expensive.

Then you need to consider how you'll get the energy out of the capacitor. As a capacitor discharges, its voltage decreases. So you'll need something like a [boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) to convert the twelve-or-less volts across the capacitor into the 12V you need for the electromagnet.

Also, this conversion is not without loss, so in practice you'll need to store more energy.

Given the large expense and size of such a large capacitor, and the engineering challenges in utilizing it, it's probably the case that a capacitor is not a good solution. A battery is probably a much better bet. A lead-acid battery is relatively cheap and has a higher energy density than capacitors. It also has the nice property of providing a terminal voltage of approximately 12V across its entire discharge curve, so you won't need a boost converter.

Comment: Thanks Phil just the information i was looking for really appreciate the advice!!!  Knowledge is power.... However it is useless unless shared. Thank you to everyone that has contributed really appreciate your thoughts and advise.